# Install4J Automation thru headless

Tags: java, jenkins, install4j

Is there any way by which we can automate the build part as we don't want GUI part, As we want to integrate build part(generate .exe part) to our CI/CD tools like Jenkins. Any suggestion by which we can accomplish headless build either thru Bat file or wrapper by using Jars.

Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

install4j has a [command line compiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/compiler.html) and integrations for [Gradle](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/gradle.html), [maven](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/maven.html) and [ant](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/ant.html).

Comment: Can you please share any sample code to which we can refer

Comment: I would have to direct you to the linked documentation.

Comment: Please suggest any sample project in which you have used, above method to incorporate CI/CD tools.

Comment: You can see the "hello" sample project for ant and Gradle build file.